# Cherrypy_handling requests

Tags: multithreading, cherrypy

I've been searching for a while now but can't find an answere.
I know that cherrypy creates a new thread for handling requests (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE etc).

Now i fetch the parameters like this:

```
...
@cherrypy.tools.json_in()
@cherrypy.tools.json_out()
def POST(self):
   Forum.lock_post.acquire()
   conn = self.io.psqlConnect(self.dict_psql)
   cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory = psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
   params = cherrypy.request.json
   ...
   return some_dict
```

As you can see im locking the thread to avoid race condition on the variable **params**. But is this really necessary? I'm asking cos if i do it like this all the other requests on POST will have to wait. Is there any better solution without locking the whole POST? I'm using **params** several times along the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a clarification, CherryPy doesn't create a new thread for each requests, it has a predetermined pool of threads (10 by default), from which indeed one thread can be used to handle a single request at a time.

As for if you should lock `cherrypy.request.json`. You really don't, there is a concept called "thread locals" on which you can have multiple references to different objects depending on which thread is accessing such object. ([python docs](http://ttps://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-local-data)).

Having said that... you should make sure that the code that you write doesn't interfere with the state of the other threads (you can use the `cherrypy.thread_data` as a quick fix).

Take a look into the cherrypy plugin architecture, if you want a resource to be shared among threads usually a plugin is the way to: http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/extend.html#plugins