# Cherrypy assignment confusion

Tags: json, cherrypy

I am a student and struggling with an assignment. Our professor wants us to create a server using cherrypy, and her test script to test the server's functionality sends json data to our sever and we must decode it. She gave us a line to help us, yet I have no idea how to use it. This is what it says in my code. What does the cherrypy.request line do, and how does it accept incoming json data? Thanks :-)

```
def GET(self):
            output = { 'result': 'success'}
    #this is the line she wants us to use below
            body = cherrypy.request.body.read(int(cherrypy.request.headers['Content-Length']))  

            try:
                    body = json.loads(body)
            except KeyError as ex:
                    output['results'] = 'error'
                    output['message'] = str(ex)
            return json.dumps(body)
```

Comment: cherrypy sets up the `cherrypy.request` object, which is a thread-local. You can access pre-processed request data using it.

Comment: In fact, the code is too complex here. Just use json tool and CherryPy will do JSON serialization for you.

Comment: Check out code snippet from here https://stackoverflow.com/q/46451347/595220

Comment: Additionally I highly recommend that you read through the docs.cherrypy.org documentation